# Unity SQLite unable to build APK after Plugin folder

Tags: c#, sqlite, unity-game-engine

i've found a guide on Github that should help me integrate SQLite over Unity in Android. [GITHUB](https://github.com/codecoding/SQLite4Unity3d.) The contents of the Plugins folder from what i know should enable Unity/Android/SQLite interoperability. I have 2 projects that i tested this out, once has a complete database (project1) and the other doesnt(project2).

ok i've decided to explicitly copy and paste the plugins to project1 which has a working SQLite database that works in the editor but whenever i try to build the app i just get a ding sound and an "empty" APK which is 0kilobytes in my recently used files in Windows 10 (even though i did not use it). same thing happens when i paste the plugins folder for project2.

NO ERROR MESSAGE. just a quick Ding sound (like the windows notification sound) and then bam, no file created.

any idea for a fix? i'm at a loss here and i'm not sure why it is a  pain to get Unity, SQLite and Android to work. or better yet do we have any alternative for SQLite that is much easier to implement?

I've also tried setting the android version target high to ICS at least but still the same issue.

using Unity and VS2015(c#).

I am able to build without the plugins folder. but when i paste it onto the project the issue i describe above happens.

Comment: Stupid question, but will it build without the plugins folder?

Comment: yes it does build without the plugins folder. any thoughts?

Comment: Open the editor log (from the downward triangle menu on the upper right hand of the log window) after a failed build and post the contents. Also post the exact contents of your plugins folder.

Comment: hi. i'm deleting this thread. i found the solution by downloading from a different source, it is building. but thanks for the replying to my issue.